# Accessing value of array inside of array in vuejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, vue.js

I am currently learning Vue3. I am trying to access the values of the array inside an array to make a nice table. Then, those values will be separated by a comma.

Here is the link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-chdcrt?

Expected output:

name | email | socialMedia

Ram | Ram@gmail.com | Weibo, Linkedln

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `array.join(character to split with)` to convert the array of social medias into a string list.
In this case it would be

```js
<td>{{ info.socialMedia.join(', ') }}</td>
```

[Project link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-v1ae5f?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FHelloWorld.vue)

Answer (score 1):

to complete your goals you should use  `Array.join()` [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join?retiredLocale=uk).
Also, I strongly recommend you use [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) when looking for built-in methods.

In your case it will be look like: 
`<td>{{ info.socialMedia.join(', ') }}</td>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use join here to [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) array of strings as:

[`live DEMO`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-2bgh89?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FHelloWorld.vue)

```
<td>{{ info.socialMedia.join(", ") }}</td>
```